# Save data from datagridview to database mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Hello I'm getting an error in the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() part I just want to save all the displayed or data content from the Datagridview to my Database.

and i get an error row 1 did not match or something like that .I input the database values from my database sql but I failed. Did anything I inputted wrong in the code.?

```vb
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim constring As String = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dat"
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO studlogs VALUES(@studtags, @idno, @lastxt, @firstxt, @middletxt, @dob, @log, @age, @timein, @crse)", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studtags", row.Cells("StudentTag").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idno", row.Cells("StudentID").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastxt", row.Cells("LastName").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstxt", row.Cells("FirstName").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middletxt", row.Cells("MiddleName").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", row.Cells("Age").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log", row.Cells("Status").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", row.Cells("Birthday").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timein", row.Cells("Timein").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crse", row.Cells("CourseSec").Value)


                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.")

End Sub


Private Sub Students_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False ' Disabled or hide (*) Symbol...

        DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False 'To hide Left indicator..
        DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.SteelBlue  'Selection backcolor....
        DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow 'Alternating Backcolor.
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = False 'Disabled  row resize...
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.MultiSelect = False
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        DataGridView1.ShowRowErrors = False
        DataGridView1.ShowCellErrors = False

        table2.Columns.Add("StudentTag", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table2.Columns.Add("StudentID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table2.Columns.Add("LastName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table2.Columns.Add("FirstName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table2.Columns.Add("MiddleName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table2.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table2.Columns.Add("Status", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table2.Columns.Add("Birthday", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table2.Columns.Add("Timein", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table2.Columns.Add("CourseSec", Type.GetType("System.String"))

        If table2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            logins.Text = table2.Rows.Count.ToString()
        End If
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table2
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: If you used data binding you would not need any of that code.  The DataAdapter would add all new rows, update all changed rows and delete and deleted rows with one line of code.  Databinding also would be unlikely to save an age, Id or time as string...or something like that.

Comment: "did not match or something like that". Why be so vague when the error message is right in front of you? Error messages are provided as an aid to diagnosing the issue. If you expect us to diagnose then give us the error message rather than some vague approximation. We could guess what it actually is but then we might guess wrong. Why should we have to guess when you already have that information?

Comment: It actually appears that you already are using data-binding, so you should be already using a data adapter. Also, instead of adding the columns to your `DataTable` yourself and specifying that they all contains `String` when clearly some of them should not, I would suggest calling `FillSchema` on your data adapter.  That will allow you to create the schema in the `DataTable` based on a database query without actually retrieving data. You can then use a command builder to generate the `InsertCommand ` if you like, or you can create it yourself but with correctly-typed parameters.

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 that's the error sir i'm sorry about forgetting that thank you

Comment: Specify the actual columns of your database